# How to invoke Discovery API from the Watson Assistant dialog?

Tags: watson-conversation, watson-discovery

How do I make a call to discovery API from Watson assistant's dialog with reference to this [page](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-actions.html#dialog-actions)

Where do I set the endpoint?

Comment: I want to supplement the previous post

"type":"client"